# copy and paste sheet name into specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I would like to copy all the sheet name in to sheet "Data".
And from D1 E1 F1 and so on.
kindly help me on this.
Below are the draft of my vba coding.
Thanks

```
Sub Compiless()
    
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Sheets("Data").Select
    
    For i = 1 To worksheets.Count

        Select Case worksheets(i).Name
        Case "Data", "Manage", "Instructions" 'Skip these sheets

        Case Else

        ActiveSheet.[D1] = ActiveSheet.Name
        
        End Select

    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. You have a better chance of receiving assistance if you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi,i have amended my coding. please help me.

Comment: Have a crack at my new solutions.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Write Sheet Names to a Worksheet

**A Quick Fix**

```
Sub Compiless()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim Destination As Worksheet: Set Destination = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = Destination.Range("D1")
    
    Dim Source As Object
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To wb.Sheets.Count
        Select Case wb.Sheets(i).Name
        Case "Data", "Manage", "Instructions" 'Skip these sheets
        Case Else
            dCell.Value = wb.Sheets(i).Name
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    
End Sub
```

**New**

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- The following will write the sheet names of the workbook containing this code, not contained in an exceptions list, to a row of a specified worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub writeSheetList()
    
    Const ExceptionsList As String = "Data,Manage,Instructions"
    Const dName As String = "Data"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "D1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim Exceptions() As String: Exceptions = Split(ExceptionsList, ",")
    
    Dim nCount As Long: nCount = wb.Sheets.Count
    Dim dat As Variant: ReDim dat(1 To nCount)
    
    Dim ssh As Object
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each ssh In wb.Sheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ssh.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            n = n + 1
            dat(n) = ssh.Name
        End If
    Next ssh
    ReDim Preserve dat(1 To n)
    
    wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, n).Value = dat

End Sub
```

**Old**

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- The following will write the sheet names of the workbook containing this code to a column in a specified worksheet whose name will not be included in the list.

---

```
Sub writeSheetListOld()

    Const dName As String = "Data"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = wb.Sheets.Count - 1
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim ssh As Object
    Dim r As Long
    
    For Each ssh In wb.Sheets
        If ssh.Name <> dName Then
            r = r + 1
            Data(r, 1) = ssh.Name
        End If
    Next ssh
    
    wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(rCount).Value = Data

End Sub
```